# Using intent to pass data with Android jetpack navigation graph

Tags: android, android-intent, kotlin, android-jetpack

I have finished implementing this new Android jetpack navigation graph into a project. I have a `ListView` that has a detailed view, defined in the nav graph.

The transitions to & from from view to view with this nav graph work great, however, I am stuck now trying to pass a data object from the `ListView` (View A, comprised of `Winter` objects) to the detailed view (View B). Before using Jetpack, this was quite simple with intents and `startActivity()`

Winter object:

```
class Winter(sportName:String, sportType: SportType, sportEquipment:ArrayList<Equipment> ) {

    var sportName = ""
    var sportType = WinterModel.SportType.board
    var sportEquipment = arrayListOf<Equipment>()

    enum class SportType(val type: String){
        board("Board"),
        ski("Ski"),
        engine("Engine")
    }

    init {
        this.sportName = sportName
        this.sportType = sportType
        this.sportEquipment = sportEquipment
    }

}
```

I would like to be able to do something like:

```
val tappedSport = winterSport[position]
val bundle = Bundle()
bundle.putString(SPORT, tappedSport)
Navigation.findNavController(view!!).navigate(R.id.winterSportDetails,bundle)
```

*Obviously that won't work, because winterSport[position] is not a string...*

**How can I pass the tapped Winter object to View B using jetpack navigation?**

**Edit: Here's how I would have done it with intents.**

View A (Sending)

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener { _, _, position, _ ->

    val tappedSport = winterSport[position]

    val detailIntent = DetailActivity.newIntent(context, tappedSport)

    startActivity(detailIntent)
}
```

View B (Receiving)

```
companion object {

    const val SPORT_NAME = "SPORT_NAME"
    const val SPORT_TYPE = "SPORT_TYPE"
    const val SPORT_EQUIPMENT = "SPORT_EQUIPMENT"

    fun newIntent(context: Context, sport: WinterModel): Intent {
        val detailIntent = Intent(context, DetailActivity::class.java)

        detailIntent.putExtra(SPORT_NAME, sport.sportName)
        detailIntent.putExtra(SPORT_TYPE, sport.sportType.type)
        detailIntent.putExtra(SPORT_EQUIPMENT, sport.sportEquipment.gear)

        return detailIntent
    }
}

//.. Then just access the info in onViewCreated
```

Comment: How would you have passed your `Winter` object via an Intent? What a Bundle accepts and what an Intent accepts are the same.

Comment: @ianhanniballake I edited my original question to show how I would handle it with intents. There doesn't seem to be a bundle.putExtra() function like with intents.

Comment: What do you think the `put` methods of `Bundle` give you but the exact things you use with `putExtra`?

Comment: I do not understand your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Extras of an Intent are stored in a Bundle. For every type that is acceptable in `putExtra()` there is an equivalent method on Bundle that accepts that same type.

For example, for a String, you'd use `putString`. Enum types are `Serializable`, so you'd use `putSerializable`. Similarly for every other type.

Comment: Are you telling me that I should not pass the object itself from A -> B (which is what I was going for), but break it apart and pass all the value types from A -> B? The winter object I posted has a bunch of properties stripped from it to make the example easier.

Comment: Regular objects can't be put into a Bundle (or, by extension, an Intent). You can have your object implement [Parcelable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable), which does allow it to be stored in a Bundle (there's the handy [Parcelize Kotlin feature](https://proandroiddev.com/parcelable-in-kotlin-here-comes-parcelize-b998d5a5fcac) that makes this a lot easier), but note that the amount of data you can put in a Bundle is **extremely limited**, so large objects and large lists shouldn't be put in Bundles (you should store them in a database and pass an id instead).